# Javascript canvas drawing - shape is filled

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a series of circles orbiting a central point, a very, *very* basic version of this:
https://mgvez.github.io/jsorrery/

I have managed this so far, but the shape is filled, and I'm not sure why. It actually looks pretty cool, but not what I wanted ;)

```js
var origin_x = 200;
var origin_y = 200;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

class planet {
 constructor(orbital_velocity, orbital_radius, radius) {
  this.orbital_velocity = orbital_velocity;
  this.orbital_radius = orbital_radius;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.draw()
 }

 draw() {
   const theta = t*this.orbital_velocity
   const x  = origin_x + this.orbital_radius*Math.cos(theta) 
   const y  = origin_y + this.orbital_radius*Math.sin(theta) 
   ctx.arc(x, y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, 'anticlockwise')
   ctx.fill();
 }
}


let t = 0;
window.setInterval(function(){
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 ctx.beginPath();
 const a = new planet(2*Math.PI, 30, 1 );
 const b = new planet(Math.PI, 50, 1 );
 const c = new planet(0.5*Math.PI, 70, 1 );
 const d = new planet(0.25*Math.PI, 90, 1 );
 t += 0.1;
}, 40);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col text-center">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've read the docs, but I can't figure out why this is happening... I need the individual circles (arcs) to be filled, not the shape between them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `ctx.beginPath()` and `ctx.closePath()`, otherwise the canvas *thinks* you are drawing a complex element/polygon and tries to fill that.

```js
var origin_x = 200;
var origin_y = 200;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

class planet {
 constructor(orbital_velocity, orbital_radius, radius) {
  this.orbital_velocity = orbital_velocity;
  this.orbital_radius = orbital_radius;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.draw()
 }

 draw() {
   const theta = t*this.orbital_velocity
   const x  = origin_x + this.orbital_radius*Math.cos(theta) 
   const y  = origin_y + this.orbital_radius*Math.sin(theta) 
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, 'anticlockwise')
   ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
 }
}


let t = 0;
window.setInterval(function(){
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 ctx.beginPath();
 const a = new planet(2*Math.PI, 30, 1 );
 const b = new planet(Math.PI, 50, 1 );
 const c = new planet(0.5*Math.PI, 70, 1 );
 const d = new planet(0.25*Math.PI, 90, 1 );
 t += 0.1;
}, 40);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col text-center">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```